# how to subtract rows and make new rows?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How I can subtract rows of my data set and make a new row for each?

data:

```
date       A    B     C
2020-01-1  2    3     4
2020-01-1  2    4     1
2020-01-1  3    2     1
```

output:

```
date                   A    B     C
2020-01-1              2    3     4
2020-02-1              2    4     1
2020-03-1               3    2     1
[2020-02-1]-[2020-01-1]   0  1   -3
[2020-03-1-[2020-02-1]     1  -2  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.append(df.iloc[:,1:].diff().iloc[1:]                    # differences
   .assign(date=df.iloc[1:,0]+' - '+df.iloc[:-1,0].values) # append dates
)
```

Output:

```
                    date    A    B    C
0              2020-01-1  2.0  3.0  4.0
1              2020-01-1  2.0  4.0  1.0
2              2020-01-1  3.0  2.0  1.0
1  2020-01-1 - 2020-01-1  0.0  1.0 -3.0
2  2020-01-1 - 2020-01-1  1.0 -2.0  0.0
```

Comment: @elham it should.

Comment: there is TpeEroor: unsupported operand type(s) for +:  int and 'str'

Comment: You need to clean your data. Make sure `A,B,C` are numerical type.

Comment: they are all numeric

Comment: the problem is the name of rows, can't add `-` between 2 dates